# Django Formset... saving User with field exclusion

Tags: django-forms

So in this formset the first field saves & updates just fine... but when I want to add a new object, it doesn't work out so well.

```
#Views.py
def edit_auto(request):
car = Auto.objects.filter(user=request.user)
CarFormSet = modelformset_factory(Auto, form=AutoForm, max_num=3)

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = CarFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=car)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save(commit=False)
        formset.user = request.user
        formset.save()

    return render_to_response('manage_users.html', {'message':'Success! The user has been updated!'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
            formset = CarFormSet(queryset=car)
return render_to_response('mycar.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#forms.py
class AutoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Auto
        user = Auto.user
        exclude = ('user',)
```

Is it something in the template? If it was a single instance of the form, `form.user = request.user` normally saves but this doesn't. Any suggestions? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the user-assigning step, just iterate over the formset.

```
...
if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = CarFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=car)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save(commit=False)
        for form in formset:
            form.user = request.user
        formset.save()
...
```

Comment: What is the `user = Auto.user` line in your form declaration doing?  That looks suspicious/wrong to me.  Are you trying to set an initial value for user?  If so, check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset).

Comment: i figured it out (i removed `user = Auto.user`):


     `if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = AutoFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=car)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save(commit=False)
            for form in formset:
                form.instance.user = request.user
            formset.save()
            return render_to_response('manage_users.html', {'message':'Success! The user has been updated!'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) `

Thanks for your help!